# html5 video jquery function not playing

Tags: html, video

Okay I'm confused. If I un-comment the alert below the video plays when I click the play button, but only while the alert is on the screen. If I comment out the alert the video doesn't play at all. I have spent the last hour researching and playing with this but can't figure it out. Suggestions for a fix?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#play').click(function(){
        if($('#player').get(0).paused){
            $('#player').get(0).play();     
            //alert('playing');
        }else{
            $('#player').get(0).pause();
        }       
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

duh...added return false and it works.